# Lighting up all elements of a poset by toggling upsets

Tags: graph-theory, boolean-functions, directed-acyclic-graph, partial-order, order-theory

I consider the following game on a finite poset $(P, <)$. At each point of the game, I have a set of elements $S$ of the poset which are "on", and all others are "off". Initially $S = \emptyset$. Each move of the game consists of choosing one element $x$ of the poset; then I consider its upset $U_x = \{y \in P \mid x \leq y\}$ and:

- If all elements of $U_x$ are off, then I can play an *on-move* on $x$, which turns all of $U_x$ on, so $S$ becomes $S \cup U_x$ (with the union being disjoint).
- If all elements of $U_x$ are on, I can play an *off-move* on $x$ and turn all of $U_x$ off, so $S$ becomes $S \setminus U_x$ (with $U_x \subseteq S$).
- Otherwise I cannot currently play on this $x$.

My goal is to switch on all elements of the poset, i.e., find a sequence of moves that reaches $S = P$, from the initial configuration $S = \emptyset$. However, I impose that for each element $x$, all my plays on $x$ in the sequence are of the same type, i.e., if I play an on-move on $x$ then I am not allowed to play an off-move on $x$ at any point of the sequence -- but I can play other on-moves on $x$ if I want. (If we don't impose this, then it's not too hard to show by induction that we can always win.)

My question is: **What are the posets on which there is a way to win the game? In particular, can we always win when $P$ is a join-semilattice, i.e., any nonempty subset of elements has a least upper bound?**

For a simple example of the game, consider $P$ with the following Hasse diagram:

[image: Easy example]

I have animated a winning strategy on the picture. Initially all vertices are off (=white). Then we do the following:

- first play an on-move on $A$ (and $S$ becomes $\{A, D, E\}$),
- then play an off-move on $D$ (and $S$ becomes $\{A\}$),
- then play an on-move on $B$ (and $S$ becomes $\{A, B, D, E\}$),
- then play an off-move on $D$ again (and $S$ becomes $\{A, B\}$),
- last play an on-move on $C$ (and $S$ becomes $P$ and I have won).

For a more complicated example, consider the following:

[image]

I have animated the steps on a winning sequence: on-move on $A$, off-move on $D$, on-move on $B$, off-move on $E$, on-move on $G$, off-move on $F$, on-move on $C$. Note that this is a bit tricky to find, e.g., starting a play with $G$ cannot win.

There is a relationship between the game and the [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#On_posets) on posets. Specifically, if I define $\mu(x) = 1 - \sum_{y < x} \mu(y)$, in particular $\mu(x) = 1$ if $x$ has no ancestors, then the sign and absolute value of $\mu(x)$ tells me which types of move I should play on $x$, and how many. In particular when $\mu(x) = 0$, we should never play on $x$, as with the vertex $H$ in the example above. Another way to see this is about a restricted way to compute the [inclusion-exclusion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) with no cancellations.

I already know that we cannot win on every poset, as a computer search by [Louis Jachiet](https://louis.jachiet.com/) turned out the following poset, where there is no winning strategy (checked by exhaustive search). There is no counterexample with less than 9 elements:

[image: A minimal pathological case]

For our purposes we are interested in knowing whether the game can always be won on *join-semilattices*, i.e., every nonempty set of elements has a least upper bound (i.e., a unique descendant which is as high as possible). This is not the case above (consider $A$ and $B$), and this requirement seems to constrain the structure of the graph, but we don't know how to prove the claim (or whether it is true). We have been running a computer search for join-semilattices on which the game cannot be won, but we haven't found a counterexample yet.

As for the motivation of the problem, it was originally about expressing certain kinds of Boolean functions using restricted classes of circuits, with connections to [safe queries over probabilistic databases](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~suciu/jacm-dichotomy.pdf).

Comment: "a least upper bound (i.e., a unique descendant which is as high as possible)."  Do you mean a unique ancestor which is as low as possible?  Oh, I see, the descendants of a node are _above_ it in the diagrams you draw.

Comment: @NealYoung: Yes I'm drawing edges from bottom to top, following the usual convention for Hasse diagrams of posets.

Answer (score 1):

Co-worker here. We haven't solved it yet, but here are a few remarks (in case it gives anyone an idea, because we are stuck).

The main thing we have for now is a partial result on so-called *crown-free lattices*. To show it, for two elements $x,y$ of the poset $P$, I say that $x$ is *covered* by $y$ if $x\geq y$, $x \neq y$, and there are no elements in between (i.e., $y$ is just above $x$ in the Hasse diagram of $P$). Let me now show claim (*): we can then assume without loss of generality that $P$ is such that:

1. there are no elements $x$ of $P$ that cover exactly one element; and
2. for every minimal element $x$ of $P$, $x$ is covered by at least two elements.

I will show this by taking a poset $P$ such that it has an $x$ satisfying condition 1. or 2., and then considering the poset $P'$ where we have removed $x$, and show that if $P'$ is winnable then so is $P$. Assume first that $x$ satisfies 1., and let $\mathbf{s}$ be a winning sequence for $P'$ (a sequence of moves that goes from $\emptyset$ to $P'$). Then it is easy to see that $\mathbf{s}$ is also a winning sequence for $P$; indeed the state of $x$ (on or off) will always follow the state of its unique child, and we never need to click on $x$ (this can also be explained by checking that $\mu_P(x) = 0$), so all moves are valid. Assume now that $x$ satisfies 2., and again let $\mathbf{s}$ be a winning sequence for $P'$. Let $p$ be the unique parent of $x$ in $P$, and let $a = \mu_P(p)$. It is easy to show that $\mu_{P'}(p) = a+1$ and that $\mu_{P'}(y) = \mu_P(y)$ for all $y \in P'$, $y \neq p$. I then consider two cases:

- $a<0$. We can then obtain a winning sequence for $P$ as follows: first, play an on-move on $x$, then play an off-move on $p$ (this is legal since $a<0$), and then play the sequence $\mathbf{s}$. Observe that we have $a+1 \leq 0$, so in the whole sequence we will only play off-moves on $p$, and it is clear that all the moves are valid and that we end up with everything being on, so that this is indeed a winning sequence for $P$.
- $a \geq 0$. In this case $a+1>0$, which mean that in $\mathbf{s}$ we will only play on-moves on $p$, and we will play at least one. We then obtain a winning sequence for $P$ as follows: play the sequence $\mathbf{s}$, but the very first time we play an on-move on $p$, play an on-move on $x$ instead. Again, it is easy to see that this is indeed a winning sequence for $P$.

This concludes the proof of claim (*).

If we look at the first example in the question, we can deal with it using claim (*): we can eliminate $E$ because it satisfies condition 1., then we can eliminate $A$, $B$ and $C$ (because they satisfy condition 2.), and we end up with only one node ($D$), and this is clearly a poset that is winnable. However for the second example in the question, we can eliminate $G$ (it satisfies condition 2.), but then there is nothing to eliminate, so here he'd need something else to show that $P'$ is winnable.

Claim (*) implies in particular that join-semilattices that are obtained from *dismantable* lattices by removing the bottom element are winnable; these are lattices that can be emptied by recursively removing the *doubly irreducible* elements, see 
*Kelly, David; Rival, Ivan*, [**Crowns, fences, and dismantlable lattices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1974-120-2), Can. J. Math. 26, 1257-1271 (1974). This paper shows in particular that dismantable lattices are exactly the lattices that are crown-free (see the paper for the definition), so if we want to solve our problem for join-semilattices only (instead of for all posets), it becomes equivalent to the following:

**Can we win for every join-semilattice that has a crown?** (Note that the second example in the question is a join-semilattice that has a crown).

Other than claim (*), we have some code ([there](https://gitlab.com/Gruyere/a-game-on-dags)) to decide if a given poset is winnable or not, and if yes to visualize the winning strategy. In particular we have generated a lot of join-semilattices and found no counter-example so far.

We are also working on a generalization of this problem: see [this note](http://mikael-monet.net/share/note.pdf).